# How to parse both parent and child XML node attributes

Tags: .net, xml, parent-child, nodes

I'm trying to get specific attribute values from an XML file an then put them into a table.

Here is an extract of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<CUSTOMER defined="true">
<FIREWALLS defined="true">
<CMA display_name="JAPAN" ssh_port="" secondary_host_ip="" collector="Collector_A"      communication="cpstat" Allow_Auto_Implementation="no" secondary_host_name=""   secondary_host_sic_name="" monitoring="yes" audit_from_clm="no" log_collection_frequency="60"   type="CMA" name="" host_name="" use_opsec_data_collection="yes" user_name="" passwd=""   use_opsec_lea="yes" os="linux" defined="true">
        <FW_CKP epasswd="" do_log_analysis="yes" defined="true" original_name="FW_A" name="FW_A"  display_name="FW_A" os="sun" user_name="" passwd="" log_collection_mode="extensive" baseline_profile="" host_name="10.10.10.1" log_server="JAPAN_Pry"/>
        <FW_CKP epasswd="" do_log_analysis="yes" defined="true" original_name="FW_B" name="FW_B" display_name="FW_B" os="sun" user_name="" passwd="" baseline_profile="" log_collection_mode="extensive" host_name="10.10.10.2" log_server="JAPAN_Pry"/>
        <FW_CKP epasswd="" do_log_analysis="yes" defined="true" original_name="FW_C" name="FW_C" display_name="FW_C" os="sun" user_name="" passwd="" baseline_profile="" log_collection_mode="extensive" host_name="10.10.10.3" log_server="JAPAN_Pry"/>
</CMA>
<CMA display_name="USA" ssh_port="" secondary_host_ip="" collector="Collector_B" communication="cpstat" Allow_Auto_Implementation="no" secondary_host_name="" secondary_host_sic_name="" monitoring="yes" audit_from_clm="no" log_collection_frequency="60" type="CMA" name="" host_name="" use_opsec_data_collection="yes" user_name="" passwd="" use_opsec_lea="yes" os="linux" defined="true">
        <FW_CKP epasswd="" do_log_analysis="yes" defined="true" original_name="FW_D" name="FW_D" display_name="FW_D" os="sun" user_name="" passwd="" baseline_profile="" log_collection_mode="extensive" host_name="10.10.10.4" log_server="USA_Pry"/>
</CMA>
</FIREWALLS>
</CUSTOMER>
```

I need to get "display_name" and "collector" values from CMA nodes. Then per each CMA nodes I need to get the associated "original_name" and "log_server" per FW_CKP child nodes. At the end, the purpose is to have a table where each rows are formated like that: [CMA NAME] - [COLLECTOR] - [ORIGINAL NAME] - [LOG SERVER NAME].

Here is my current code:

```
' Load XML file
            doc.Load(tb_FilePath.Text)
'XML node path for CMA and FW_CKP
        CMA_Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/CUSTOMER /FIREWALLS/CMA")
        FW_CKP_Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/CUSTOMER /FIREWALLS/CMA/FW_CKP")

        'loop to go through each CAM nodes
        For Each CMA_Node As System.Xml.XmlElement In CMA_Nodes

            'operation inside the CMA balise
            CMA_Name = CMA_Node.Attributes(0).InnerText
            CMA_Collector = CMA_Node.Attributes(3).InnerText

            'loop to go through each FW_CKP nodes
            For Each FW_CKP_Node As System.Xml.XmlElement In FW_CKP_Nodes

                'Operation inside the FW_CKP baslise
                Original_Name = FW_CKP_Node.Attributes(3).InnerText
                Log_Server = FW_CKP_Node.Attributes(12).InnerText

                'update the table with the CMA name
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {CMA_Name, CMA_Collector, Original_Name, Log_Server})

            Next

        Next
```

So the code is going through the first CMA nodes and then instead of ONLY looking at the FW_CKP child nodes, it is going through all of them on the XML file and putting addional rows in the table (wrong ones).

How can I get the below result:

[CMA] - [COLLECTOR] - [ORIGINAL NAME] - [LOG SERVER NAME]

JAPAN - Collector_A - FW_A - JAPAN_Pry

JAPAN - Collector_A - FW_B - JAPAN_Pry

JAPAN - Collector_A - FW_C - JAPAN_Pry

USA - Collector_B - FW_D - USA_Pry

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are searching for the FW_CKP nodes globally, rather than with respect to each CMA node.

But if all FW_CKP nodes are the only direct children of a CMA node, you could just use CMA_Node.ChildNodes:

```
   For Each CMA_Node As System.Xml.XmlElement In CMA_Nodes

        'operation inside the CMA balise
        CMA_Name = CMA_Node.Attributes(0).InnerText
        CMA_Collector = CMA_Node.Attributes(3).InnerText

        'loop to go through each FW_CKP nodes
        For Each FW_CKP_Node As System.Xml.XmlElement In CMA_Node.ChildNodes

            'Operation inside the FW_CKP baslise
            Original_Name = FW_CKP_Node.Attributes(3).InnerText
            Log_Server = FW_CKP_Node.Attributes(12).InnerText

            'update the table with the CMA name
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {CMA_Name, CMA_Collector, Original_Name, Log_Server})

        Next

    Next
```